# Connecting to MySQL database via SSH

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, paramiko

I am trying to connect my python program to a remote MySQL Database via SSH.

I am using Paramiko for SSH and SQLAlchemy.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import paramiko
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', port=port, username='user', password='pass')

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@host/db')
```

I am getting an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mcsdev.croft-it.com' (60)")
```

Comment: If the server is already available via a hostname, why not grant access on the database from remote itself? seems a bit redundant to connect via ssh and after that to the mysql server

Comment: Its because the program will be distributed to many different site, which we will not know the IP for. I could add a wildcard but I don't think this will be ideal

Comment: But if there is a public ip-address to every server this application is running on (for the ssh part), it is possible to connect to the database itself.

Comment: But if we do not know the IP address we can't add it. Also it could be running at sites that does not have a static IP

Comment: But then, how it is possible to connect via ssh?

Comment: Via the IP of the server the database sits on

Comment: But again, if the IP of the database server is static, use a damn direct mysql-connection ... Nevermind

Comment: On the VPS you have to add allowed host's (IP's that can remotely access the database.) If i do not know the IP of the client or the client does not have a static IP, how can I add it. If the VPS had no security for remote database acces then i would agree with you. If you do not understand thats fine. Don't waist your time with it

Comment: You need to give the user perm. in the mysql database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry I posted a duplicated answer before. Here is a more elaborated answer tailored exactly to your question ;)

If you still in need of connecting to a remote MySQL db via SSH I have used a library named sshtunnel, that wraps ands simplifies the use of paramiko (a dependency of the sshtunnel).

With this code I think you will be good to go:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server =  SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('host', 22),
     ssh_password="password",
     ssh_username="username",
     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))

server.start()

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:%s/db' % server.local_bind_port)

# DO YOUR THINGS

server.stop()
```

Comment: Do we need to handle connection and closing the connection manually if I were to use this with Flask?

Answer (score 2):

This code work for me

```
        import pymysql
        import paramiko
        from paramiko import SSHClient
        from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine

        #ssh config
        mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('your/user/location/.ssh/id_rsa')             
        ssh_host = 'your_ssh_host'
        ssh_user = 'ssh_host_username'
        ssh_port = 22  

        #mysql config         
        sql_hostname = 'your_mysql_host name'
        sql_username = 'mysql_user'
        sql_password = 'mysql_password'
        sql_main_database = 'your_database_name'
        sql_port = 3306
        host = '127.0.0.1'



        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (ssh_host, ssh_port),
                ssh_username=ssh_user,
                ssh_pkey=mypkey,
                remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:              

            engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://'+sql_username+':'+sql_password+'@'+host+':'+str(tunnel.local_bind_port)+'/'+sql_main_database)
            connection = engine.connect()
            print('engine creating...')
            sql = text(""" select * from nurse_profiles np limit 50""")
            nurseData = connection.execute(sql)
            connection.close()


            nurseList = []
            for row in nurseData:
                nurseList.append(dict(row))
            print('nurseList len: ', len(nurseList))
            print('nurseList: ', nurseList)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using external `ubuntu server`

With `ssh key` on digital ocean

The accepted answer did not work for me, I had to specify the `ssh_private_key`, which is the path to your private key

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('133.22.166.19', 22),
     ssh_password="123ABC123",
     ssh_username="erfan",
     ssh_private_key=r'C:\Users\Erfan\.ssh\id_rsa',
     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)

server.start()

engine = create_engine(
    f'mysql+mysqldb://root:safepassword123@127.0.0.1:{server.local_bind_port}'
)
dbs = engine.execute('SHOW DATABASES;')
for db in dbs:
    print(db)

server.stop()
```